# JSF condition in xhtml with AJAX alternative to JSTL

Tags: ajax, jsf, jstl

What is alternative to JSTIL in JSF. I would like to have a condition in xhtlm in AJAX.

```
<p:commandButton id="button" value="Send">                                   
         <f:ajax event="click"  listener="#{messageControler.wniosekWyslany()}"/> 
         <f:ajax event="click"  listener="#{messageControler.wniosekNieWyslany()}"/> 
</p:commandButton>
```

First ajax should be action when boolean = true, secound false.  Me bean return boolean value, so it is good to base on that but I do not know how. I teste JSTL but in JSF it does not works correctly.

Comment: this is 'businesslogic' and should not be in the view. Do the if-then in one method server side in a bean

Comment: Ok I understand mvc model, so in that way how to start ajax from bean? Should I use: FacesContext?

Comment: Ok, it was a good idea, I moved this to bean:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is businesslogic and should not be done in the view. Create one ajax listener and do the if/then in the bean

xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton id="button" value="Send">                                   
         <f:ajax event="click"  listener="#{messageControler.doSend()}"/> 
</p:commandButton>
```

bean:

```
public void doSend() {
   if (myBoolean) {
      wniosekWyslany();
   else {
    wniosekNieWyslany();
   } 
}
```